# Are stacks and queues passed like arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, queue

I wanted to ask this because we can change the content of an array passed to  a function without passing reference but its not same with stacks and queues.Can you tell how these two are passed to a
function then.

Comment: They will be passed however you choose to pass them.

Comment: How do you think that arrays get passed as a parameter? What does your function that takes an array look like?

Comment: You don't actually pass the array, you pass a pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that Array is basically a sequence of memory locations directly accessible with a pointer.
As against this, `stacks` and `queues` are containers, whom you instantiate.

---

```
void foo(std::stack<int> st) { //pass by value
//whatever
}

void foo(std::stack<int>& st) { //pass by reference
//whatever
}

void foo(std::stack<int>* st) { //pass by pointer
//whatever
}

std::stack<int> stack; //instantiation
foo(stack); //calling the function
foo(&stack); //when you need to pass by pointer (never used)
```

Comment: hi d4rk4ng31, if you pass it by pointer (&stack). Is it pointing to the top of the array? or the bottom?

Comment: @Fernand `&stack` points to the stack object itself, not to any of its elements.